# Updating or changing style of label using properties entered by user on entry widget tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my Gui Application I have buttons for each widget.If the user click on button named as label a label widget will be formed on window.I am asking the user to set label properties (bg color and fg color) through entry widget and i need to update that existing label using those properties.
Is there any way to do this?

```
from tkinter import *
def try1():
    w=Tk()
    l=Label(w,text="Hi")
    l.pack()
win=Tk()
b=Button(win,text="Label",command=try1)
b.pack()
ety_bgcolor=Entry(win,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
ety_bgcolor.pack()
ety_fgcolor=Entry(win,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
ety_fgcolor.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

Misunderstood the question edit:

```
from tkinter import *
def try1():
    w=Tk()
    l=Label(w,text="Hi")
    l.config(bg=bgcolor.get())
    l.config(fg=fgcolor.get())
    l.pack()

win=Tk()
b=Button(win,text="Label",command=try1)
b.pack()

bgcolor = StringVar()
ety_bgcolor=Entry(win,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove",textvariable=bgcolor)
ety_bgcolor.pack()
fgcolor = StringVar()
ety_fgcolor=Entry(win,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove",textvariable=fgcolor)
ety_fgcolor.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

If i understand you correctly you want the main window to get a new label when the user clicks the button?
If so you need to pass the main window to the function, either using the global name or passing it as a variable in the function using a lambda function.

Using global:

```
from tkinter import *
def try1():
    w=win # referencing the main window globally
    l=Label(w,text="Hi")
    l.pack()

win=Tk()
b=Button(win,text="Label",command=try1)
b.pack()
ety_bgcolor=Entry(win,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
ety_bgcolor.pack()
ety_fgcolor=Entry(win,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
ety_fgcolor.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

With the lambda method:

```
from tkinter import *
def try1(w): # getting the main window passed
    l=Label(w,text="Hi")
    l.pack()

win=Tk()
b=Button(win,text="Label",command = lambda: try1(win)) # passing the main window.
b.pack()
ety_bgcolor=Entry(win,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
ety_bgcolor.pack()
ety_fgcolor=Entry(win,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
ety_fgcolor.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

if you want the colors to be set, you have to add string variables to the entry field and reference those when setting the labels config settings.

```
from tkinter import *
def try1(w):
    l=Label(w,text="Hi")
    l.config(bg=bgcolor.get())
    l.config(fg=fgcolor.get())
    l.pack()

win=Tk()
b=Button(win,text="Label",command = lambda: try1(win))
b.pack()

bgcolor = StringVar()
ety_bgcolor=Entry(win,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove",textvariable=bgcolor)
ety_bgcolor.pack()
fgcolor = StringVar()
ety_fgcolor=Entry(win,font=("",13,""), borderwidth=2, relief="groove",textvariable=fgcolor)
ety_fgcolor.pack()


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are somewhat right.But i have two tkinter windows.On 1st window i have a button ,2 entry widgets for label bg and fg color.If i click on it a label would be formed on a second window.If the user enters bg and fg color on first window entry widgets the color should automatically change on the label in second window and this should continuosly happen

Comment: @Vijay oh, i misunderstood the question. Added a new way in the answer i posted which does this. But when you say continuously, should it create a new window every single time, or change the existing window?

Comment: _"if you want the colors to be set, you have to add string variables "_ - that's not correct. You don't _have_ to use string variables. You can get values from entry widgets without string variables.

Comment: @en_lorithai,it should change in the existing window only

Answer (score 0):

Use `configure` method to change `Label` properties.

Example to change bg color and fg color:

```
label.configure(background='yellow')
label.configure(foreground='red')
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to call the `get` methods on the entry widgets to get their value before creating the label.

```
def try1():
    ...
    bg = ty_bgcolor.get()
    fg = ety_fgcolor
    l=Label(w,text="Hi", background=bg, foreground=fg)
...
```

Comment: No,I should get the value after creating the label and update it